# Reading char-by-char silently does not work

Tags: bash, terminal, terminal-emulator, read

I'm trying to read user input char by char, silently, as follows:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
  read -s -N 1
  ...
done
```

While this loop works perfectly using VNC (`xterm`), it works only partially using putty (xterm) or a Linux terminal, and most of other text terminals.

The problem is encountered when I become "wild" with the keyboard and striking multiple keys at the same time, and than **some of the keys are echoed despite of the -s mode**.

I've also tried to redirect output and `stty -echo`. while the first did not make any difference, the latter would be somehow helpful, minimizing the "echo"s to be less frequent, but not perfect.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't that n in the `read -s -N 1` command be lower case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read -s` disables the terminal `echo` only for the duration of that `read` command. So if you type something in between two `read` commands, the terminal driver will `echo` it back.

You should disable `echo` and then call `read` in your loop without `-s`:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  saved=$(stty -g)
  stty -echo
fi
while read -rN1; do
  ...
done
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  stty "$saved"
fi
```